# How to custom Regex City from address column for BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to make a regular expression from address column to get district and city which can match text in Following way:

address :

```
Regency, Jl. Mawar No.1, Kenari, Kec. Percut Sei Tuan, Kabupaten Deli Serdang, Sumatera Utara 20671, Indonesia
```

Result :

```
Kabupaten Deli Serdang, Sumatera Utara
```

How to Regex in bigQuery?

Result :

```
Kabupaten Deli Serdang, Sumatera Utara
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### RegExp Approach

You can use a regular expression here to match on the 5 digits of the postal code using `\d{5}`. Then you can simple take the two sets of words that come before that, between commas `, <some words> , <some words> \d{5}`. Use a capture group `()` to extract only what you want.

Overall, it looks like this:

```
WITH example AS (
  SELECT 'Regency, Jl. Mawar No.1, Kenari, Kec. Percut Sei Tuan, Kabupaten Deli Serdang, Sumatera Utara 20671, Indonesia' as address
)

SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(
  address,
  r',\s([^,]+,\s[^,]+)\s\d{5},') AS match
FROM example
```

Output: `Kabupaten Deli Serdang, Sumatera Utara`

### Tokenizing Approach

However, this is potentially error prone since the format could change for different addresses. We can also tokenize (split) into pieces using the `,` boundary.

In BigQuery we can make an array of values, and then choose the value at the index desired. See below:

```
-- Get all address parts split by commas and trimmed
WITH example AS (
  SELECT 'Regency, Jl. Mawar No.1, Kenari, Kec. Percut Sei Tuan, Kabupaten Deli Serdang, Sumatera Utara 20671, Indonesia' as address
)

SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(address, r',?\s?([^,]+)') AS address_parts
```

[image]
FROM example

`OFFSET(index)` lets you grab the parts you want:

-- Get only the 5th and 6th address sections
WITH example2 AS (
SELECT 'Regency, Jl. Mawar No.1, Kenari, Kec. Percut Sei Tuan, Kabupaten Deli Serdang, Sumatera Utara 20671, Indonesia' as address
)

```
SELECT
 REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(address, r',?\s?([^,]+)')[OFFSET(3)] AS address_section_5,
 REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(address, r',?\s?([^,]+)')[OFFSET(4)] AS address_section_6
FROM example2
```

[image]

Comment: how if I want result this:

`Kec. Percut Sei Tuan, Kabupaten Deli Serdang` ?

Comment: @Alea, it all depends on the format of your data. What is consistent for all data? For example, will a comma always separate a fixed number of sections? Will the two values you want always be the 5th and 6th block of text?

Comment: @Alea please see the updated answer. Hope that helps. If it does, please up vote :)

Comment: Nice efforts at arriving answer; +1;
I was just curious about answer when I saw this question;